# What does the VisualStudio Dataset visualizer exclaimation mark mean?

Tags: visual-studio, dataset, visualizer

Some rows in the dataset visualizer have an exclamation mark for each column, other rows have the data as expected. I have been unable to track down a description for the exclamation mark or indeed any symbol within the dataset visualizer.

What does the VisualStudio Dataset visualizer exclaimation mark mean?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know but try opening on the tables not the datasets (Seems to work better)

Answer (score 1):

It means the data is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldnt say it means the data is deleted because i've had the same issue many times which prompted me to create my own visualizer to see if that had the same problems.

Anyway, its evolved a bit and available for free download from [www.srsoftware.co.uk](http://www.srsoftware.co.uk/portal/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&layout=blog&id=38&Itemid=65)